# Javascript: Help - Extracting object from another nested object from JSON String

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I like to use the wikipedia entry API.

Ok, my JSON request looks like this:

```
var request = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=berlin';

$.getJSON(request, function(data) {
   console.log(data)
})
```

What I get is something like this:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"411322":{"pageid": 411322,"ns":0,"title":"Berlin","extract":"entry-text."}}}}
```

But how to extract the information with JSON extraction.

I tried to do:

```
var x=data.query.pages
```

But that didn't work for me, to extract **Title** and **extract-text**.

Comment: Use `var x = JSON.parse(data);` then you can do the extraction

Comment: @DavidR Nope, when I parse the data I always get this error:             `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object".`